# What simple and light Java library to use for WGS84 to UTM conversion?

Tags: coordinates, java, coordinate-system

Geotools and Geotoolkit are huge and complicated.

CTS (1.3.3 from Maven) failed on me by not even being able to run its own test example (slightly modified https://github.com/orbisgis/cts/blob/master/src/test/java/org/cts/op/EPSGTransform.java gave me "This registry EPSG is not supported" while I did not even touch those strings).

So, are there any alternatives that are easy to use, not require additional libraries if possible (even loggers are annoying enough) and are free software?

All I want to do is turn some WGS84 coordinates to UTM32N (EPSG:25832) in Java.

Comment: GeoTools is just 2 jars to do this :-)

Comment: Last time I tried Geotools it was an afternoon of annoyed frustration. Which jars do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GeoTools Referencing FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html#q-can-i-just-use-referencing-without-the-rest-of-geotools) -

> Can I just use Referencing without the rest of GeoTools? 
>   Yes, you will
>   need to use the metadata module, and one of the epsg modules. Along
>   with their dependencies such as units.

Then all you need to do is:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:25832");
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform( sourceGeometry, transform);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added gt-metadata-13.1.jar and gt-epsg-hsql-13.1.jar to my project. Now I am stuck again. How do I create the CRSs and what is the JTS class here? I do use JTS standalone together with JUMP so far.

edit: Ok, I figured out the CRS creation but I see you added it too. Thanks! Still mystified about the "JTS".

Comment: For WGS84 to UTM32N, your source CRS will be 4326 and your target CRS will be 32632 -- EPSG as the authority.

Comment: looks like the FAQ is economical - you need gt-api too to get JTS (though technically you don't need it for reprojection).

Comment: if you are really strapped for space just use: final double[] array = new double[transform.getTargetDimensions()];
        copy(source, array);
        transform.transform(array, 0, array, 0, 1);

        switch (transform.getTargetDimensions()) {
        case 3:
            dest.z = array[2]; // Fall through

        case 2:
            dest.y = array[1]; // Fall through

        case 1:
            dest.x = array[0]; // Fall through

        case 0:
            break;
        }

Comment: I had gotten it work with gt-jts-wrapper-13.1.jar too, gt-api-13.1.jar works too. No idea what the difference is... Launch takes a good couple of seconds but I guess that is Geotools for me.

Thank you!

Comment: First time you use it, there is a delay to unpack the epsg db into tmp